# bootstrap div breaks line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 " align="center"> <img  src="" class="img-circle img-responsive"> </div>
                <div ng-switch on="editMode" class=" col-lg-8 ">
                  <div ng-switch-when="true">
                    <a href ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-primary">CANCEL</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">CHANGE PASSWORD</a>
                    <div ng-switch on="user.status">
                      <div ng-switch-when="ENABLED">
                        <a href ng-click="disableUser()" class="btn btn-primary">DISABLE</a>
                      </div>
                      <div ng-switch-default>
                        <a href ng-click="enableUser()" class="btn btn-primary">ENABLE</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div ng-switch-default>
                    <a href ng-click="editUser()" class="btn btn-primary">EDIT</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The problem is that the dib breaks the line, instead of getting 3 aligned buttons in the same row, one of them breaks to another line.

[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Regards,
Ido

Comment: Your example does not show Bootstrap CSS interacting with any `<div>` element.  Are you trying to create a Button Group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the angular's divs have `display: block` by default. Either style it to inline-block or use ng-if instead of switch:

```
<a href ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-primary">CANCEL</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">CHANGE PASSWORD</a>
<a ng-if="user.status=='enabled'" href ng-click="disableUser()" class="btn btn-primary">DISABLE</a>
<a ng-if="user.status!='enabled'" href ng-click="enableUser()" class="btn btn-primary">ENABLE</a>
```

Comment: Thanks,  This did it... and it is also much more simple

Comment: Good luck with your project. Angular is great, isn't it

Answer (score 0):

This is going to render slightly off due to your Angular code providing an option for two different buttons, but it looks like making use of `.btn-toolbar` and `.btn-group` may offer you the best solution.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-toolbar">
 <div class="btn-group">
  <a href ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-primary">CANCEL</a>
 </div>
  
 <div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">CHANGE PASSWORD</a>
 </div>
  
 <div class="btn-group ng-switch on="user.status">
  <div ng-switch-when="ENABLED"><a href ng-click="disableUser()" class="btn btn-primary">DISABLE</a></div>
  <div ng-switch-default><a href ng-click="enableUser()" class="btn btn-primary">ENABLE</a></div>
 </div>
</div>
```